# AppDelegate window.rootViewController Property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with my iOS app. It is based on storyboards. So to set the rootViewController property it should be enough to set the "Initial View Controller" property in Interface Builder and the MainInterface-Property in the project settings to the name of my storyboard. Still I always get the message "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch". 
I do several things in the applicationDidFinishLaunching section but even if everything except return YES; is commented out, I get the message.
How can I fix this warning? Or can I ignore it as everything works?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have any view controller files?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You mean ViewController classfiles? It is a standard utility app but the two views are embedded in navigation controllers. Also I am using cocoapods if this is somehow important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an activity indicator in your app delegate or root view controller by chance?  If so, it might be setting itself as the root.  Move the display of the indicator to somewhere after your main views are set up.

Comment: No I do not use the activity indicator. In the AppDelegate I almost only setup reachability.

Comment: You brought me on the right track. It was SVProgressHUD which I used in viewWillAppear. I moved the code to viewDidAppear and the warning is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
InitialViewController initial = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STORYBOARDID"];

window.rootViewController = initial;

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;}
```

Comment: I tried this an it does not help. Thanks anyway. I found out that in fact the windows.rootViewController is set correctly to an instance of UINavigationController but still I get the warning. It is the same with your code.

Comment: Try this one                               UINavigationViewController *navigation = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STORYBOARDID"];
InitialViewController *initial = [navigation.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];                                                     window.rootViewController = initial;

Comment: With this code the warning is gone but it bypasses the navigation controller. This means I don't have a UINavigationbar anymore.